# Wordpress adding different metaboxes not saving

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add many metaboxes with different inputs. I added metaboxes and I want to call each metabox seperatly. 
Sample code:

```
    add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'dm_meta_box');
    function dm_meta_box() {
        add_meta_box("dm-slides", "Slider", 'dm_slides_box', "dm", "normal");
    }

    function dm_slides_box() {
    global $post;
    $dm_slides = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_dm_slides231211ab", true);
    $dm_slides = ($dm_slides != '') ? json_decode($dm_slides) : array();

    $dm_title = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_dm_slides231211bc", true);
    $dm_title = ($dm_title != '') ? json_decode($dm_title) : array();

    $dm_link = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_dm_slides231211bf", true);
    $dm_link = ($dm_link != '') ? json_decode($dm_link) : array();

    $html = '<input type="hidden" name="dm_slider_box_nonce" value="' . wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)) . '" />';
...
}
```

Save:

```
add_action('save_post', 'dm_save_slider_info');
function dm_save_slider_info($post_id) {
   if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['dm_slider_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    if ('dm' == $_POST['post_type'] && current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
        $dm_slides = (isset($_POST['dm_slider_fields']) ? $_POST['dm_slider_fields'] : '');
        $dm_slides = strip_tags(json_encode($dm_slides));
        update_post_meta($post_id, "_dm_slides231211ab", $dm_slides);  

        $dm_title = (isset($_POST['dm_title']) ? $_POST['dm_title2'] : '');
        $dm_title = strip_tags(json_encode($dm_title));
        update_post_meta($post_id, "_dm_slides231211bc", $dm_title);          

        $dm_link = (isset($_POST['dm_link']) ? $_POST['dm_link2'] : '');
        $dm_link = strip_tags(json_encode($dm_link));
        update_post_meta($post_id, "_dm_slides231211bf", $dm_link);      

    } else {
        return $post_id;
    }
}
```

I think the problem is in save post but I tried and can't figure it out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is what I use inside `save_post` for debugging purposes: `wp_die( sprintf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $_POST, true ) ) );`

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed

```
  global $post;
```

in `function dm_save_slider_info()`

Comment: OP is not using `$post` inside the function so it wouldn't be the cause of the error. In any case, no need to declare it, just use all parameters from [`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)

Comment: I rewrite parameters and its worked, really don't understand why its not worked or why its worked now :) Anyway thanks for your support @brasofilo